# Gatling Scripts- how can I feed the eventdatetime in the below request with different epoch time

Tags: scala, gatling

Gatling Scripts- How can I feed the eventDateTime in the below request with different epoch time as a feeder too. The Id is feed through the feeder in a circular way. the Below request is in a file which is fed using a ELFileBody. The event-new.json looks like

```
{
  "events": [
    {
      "eventDataModel": {
        "eventStatus": "ON",
        "eventDateTime": 1598271042436
      },
      "transactionModel": {
        "id": "${ID}"
      }
    },
    {
      "eventDataModel": {
        "eventStatus": "ON",
        "eventDateTime": 1598271043436
      },
      "transactionModel": {
        "id": "${ID}"
      }
    },
    {
      "eventDataModel": {
        "eventStatus": "ON",
        "eventDateTime": 1598271044436
      },
      "transactionModel": {
        "id": "${ID}"
      }
    },
    {
      "eventDataModel": {
        "eventStatus": "ON",
        "eventDateTime": 1598271045436
      },
      "transactionModel": {
        "id": "${ID}"
      }
    },
    {
      "eventDataModel": {
        "eventStatus": "ON",
        "eventDateTime": 1598271046436
      },
      "transactionModel": {
        "id": "${ID}"
      }
    },
    {
      "eventDataModel": {
        "eventStatus": "ON",
        "eventDateTime": 1598271047436
      },
      "transactionModel": {
        "id": "${ID}"
      }
    },
    {
      "eventDataModel": {
        "eventStatus": "ON",
        "eventDateTime": 1598271048436
      },
      "transactionModel": {
        "id": "${ID}"
      }
    },
    {
      "eventDataModel": {
        "eventStatus": "OFF",
        "eventDateTime": 1598271049436
      },
      "transactionModel": {
        "id": "${ID}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

above is the event-new.json which is been posted using the gatling script
snippet from gatling script

```
val idFeeder = csv("Id.csv").circular
val trip_dte2 = scenario("Event")
                    .feed(idFeeder)
                    .exec(http("event")
                    .post( event_url)
                    .headers(headers)
                    .body(ElFileBody("event-new.json")).asJSON
                    .check(status.is(201)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Gatling 3.3:

```scala
.exec { session =>
  session.set("timestamp", System.currentTimeMillis())
}
```

and then replace `1598271049436` with `${timestamp}`.

Or, [coming in Gatling 3.4](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/3895): directly replace `1598271049436` with `${currentTimeMillis()}` if it's fine for you to have different values for each occurrence in your JSON payload.

Comment: would it work in gatling 3.3  if eventDateTime  is different within each eventDatamodel in the payload. its an increment of each second.

Comment: You would have to generate as many attributes as you have eventDatamodels. The other possibility would be to craft the whole body String in a function instead of using Gatling Expression Language. Check the doc or the Tutorial #4: https://gatling.io/gatling-frontline/resources/

Comment: i was able to craft the whole body in a string and it works for 1 user for 5 seconds but not when i run 5 users for 5 seconds